# How to change many2one value field name in odoo 12?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

hi when i use many2one function in odoo 12, and i have many2one relation between them (class) why i am getting a table name and id (that generate automatically looks like by odoo ORM)? and the other odoo example is not? how do i change this value?

here is how my code looked like, below is my model :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class SalesorderSalesorder(models.Model):
    _name = 'salesorder.salesorder'

    no_faktur = fields.Char(String='No Faktur', required=True)
    kd_sales = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Kode Sales')
    details = fields.One2many('salesorderdetails','no_faktur','List Item')


    class SalesOrderDetails(models.Model):
        _name = 'salesorderdetails'

        no_faktur = fields.Many2one('salesorder.salesorder')
        kd_produk = fields.Many2one('ms_produk.ms_produk','Kode Product',required=True)
```

and here is how it looked like :
[image]

and i have these column in my database :

[image]

i want to show kd_produk instead of table name and id, how do i change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `name_search` fucntion use value defined in `_rec_name`  (default as "name"), but your model not have field `name`. So just add in your model:

> _rec_name = "your_field_you_want_to_show_on_name_search"

Another way is modify function `name_get`

Answer (score 1):

Add `_rec_name` as `kd_produk` field in your `ms_produk.ms_produk` model,

Eg:

```
   class MsProduk(models.Model):
      _name = 'ms_produk.ms_produk'
      _rec_name = 'kd_produk'
```